# Cucumber Js - How to run the features [Windows]

Tags: node.js, cucumberjs

I'm trying to learn cucumber and so far got a grip on installing nodejs, cucumber, creating package.json, storing features files and steps. But when I'm trying to run using windows command prompt, I'm getting the below shown error.

project structure

```
features
  - example.feature
  - step_definitions
    - steps.js
  - support (nothing here yet)
node_modules (cucumber installed locally)
package.json
```

I started executing commands from the bin folder to ensure cucumberjs works and it echo'd out the version number 3.1.0

```
C:\Test Project\node_modules\.bin>cucumberjs -v
```

and then began to run the feature file

```
C:\Test Project\node_modules\.bin>cucumberjs "C:\Test Project\features\example.feature"
```

and it errors here

Note: If i install the cucumber globally then it works, this error happens when I install cucumber locally

Any help pointing out where I'm going wrong will be much appreciated 
[image: Error]

Answer (score 2):

I haven't figured out what's the reason behind the error but managed to run the features files by adding the following to the project package.json and running cli npm run cucumber

```
"scripts": {
    "cucumber": "cucumberjs ./features"
 },
```

Comment: This worked for me.

`node .\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\bin\cucumber-js .\test\features`